# How we can add marker to open map

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

How we can add marker to open map. Link for refrance

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API

Comment: Not really a programming question. Take a look at Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: Can you explain in a few more words what actually it is that you are trying to do, and what you have tried already?  It isn't really clear from your question currently.